# Magento 2.4.3-p3 cron not running, but works manually

Tags: cron, magento2.4.3

This is an intermittent problem as sometimes order confirmation emails are received, i.e. the cronjob runs automatically and doesn't remain as 'pending' in cron_schedule table. But most of the time it's stuck as pending as cron doesn't run. (php bin/magento cron:run works).

I'm getting mulitple errors in var/log/magento.cron.log:

```
Magento supports PHP 7.3.0 or later. Please read https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html
```

Although, PHP 7.4.32 is installed and crontab is valid:

```
/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/bin/php /home/****/public_html/bin/magento cron:run 2>&1 | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /home/****/public_html/var/log/magento.cron.log
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That path looks like php7.2

/opt/cpanel/ea-**php72**/root/usr/bin/php -v

Paste above command in console, I bet it will show 7.2

And... What about pasting just **php -v**?

Not sure what would be the right path in your server, maybe replacing that **ea-php72** by **ea-php74**? If not, contact your hosting provider

Comment: Many thanks. Changing the command to `/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/bin/php` got rid of the error, but it still doesn't run automatically, only manually with `php bin/magento cron:run`.

Comment: I've submitted a ticket with the host and will update here 

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer as valid if it helped

Comment: Thanks for your help, rep and accept done. I also needed to flush the magento cache. All working now.